# Is there a different way to pass a prop to an element in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array which has **components** in this structure

```js
let array = [
  {
    id: uniqueKeyFunction(), 
    element: <Component key={uniqueKeyFunction() />} />
  }
]
```

I would like to pass that id as a prop to the component, maybe like add it in the map function in the render. Currently the map function looks like

```
array.map(arr=>arr.element)
```

Is there a way to add a prop in this structure since I may not be able to add it at the array level?

Comment: Maybe, you can define <Component /> at the outside of array. Then send it as a props. <Component array = {array} />. Inside of Component, take it as props and map it. props.array.map(arr=> arr.element). I hope it helps you

Comment: i would do it like this, `array.map(arr=> {                                                                    
    const Element = arr.element;                                                                                                      
     return <Element />                                                                                                            
  }`

Comment: @TimoDevs, this doesn't quite cut it, it raises errors, only works if the return statement is `return Element` which still leads me back to the same problem

Comment: @OnurDoğan , I don't quite get it. The components I'm mapping out are <input /> they can't take arrays as props. If that's what you meant

Comment: @TimoDevs , aah nailed it, in the array, Instead of declaring the component as <Component />, i declare it as `Component` this works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```js
const array = [{ id: uniqueKeyFunction(), element: Component }];

return array.map(({ id, element: Element }) => <Element key={id} someProp={id} />)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement.

`React.cloneElement`

It allows you to override props of a existing component - it's not exactly what you wanted, but maybe close enough?